# how to make single wordpress page multi language?

Tags: wordpress, multilingual

I want to create a  multi language WordPress page (i-e: only page not the all content): it should have a drop-down button after clicking.

I need to choose language for translating on that language and display in translated result on page.

Comment: There must a be a plugin for this. Did you have a look on Google ?

Comment: @Random Yes I have a look but that is for whole page translator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally you should look at something like WPML https://wpml.org/ but I understand that might be overkill for your needs - instead then try this https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-content-by-country/ and make use of the shortcodes it uses. You can build your own dropdown switcher to trigger which bit of content gets shown.

Comment: Thanks for reply but it's not working any other options?

Comment: @Sanjeev I think before thinking about other solutions, you may try to make "custom-content-by-country" work, since it should be your best shot. If you can't make it work, you would have to code it yourself, and you may have more troubles than just making the plugin to work...

Comment: Yes please try that plugin "it's not working" could relate to anything. If that plugin does not work for you and you have properly tried it then fair enough. If it does not work explain what you did and what did not work etc...